# Contributing pentesting tool to (Kali) Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I had recently seen that there are about 60 information gathering tools in Kali Linux.

I just thought of contributing a single open source software/tool that has all(and even more) features of those pre-existing tools. It has many advantages(size, features, speed, integrity etc).

Is it possible to contribute to Linux (especially Kali) this software? If yes, please tell how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t speak for Kali Linux, but as I understand it, you need to file a “New tool request” in the [Kali bug tracker](http://bugs.kali.org/). Before doing that though you need to make your software available somewhere, with a license that’s appropriate for Kali.

The same goes for most Linux distributions: once your software is available somewhere, you can file a request to have it packaged for distribution. Since most are volunteer driven, you’ll get better results if your software is widely used, and even better results if you learn how to package software and make it available in the distributions yourself.

Comment: Any tips on how to package softwares better?

Comment: Better than what? The issue isn’t really the packaging, it’s getting your package into distributions; you need to focus on the social side of that. Start by reading your distribution’s documentation, especially the parts describing how to contribute.